# Mosquitto can't edit config file because of error?

Tags: raspberry-pi, config, mosquitto

I completely installed everything fresh to a Raspberry Pi and installed Mosquitto. Many online instructions state that you should put `listener 1883` and `allow_anonymous true` at the end of the config file `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` to allow remote access etc.

But as soon as I put these two twos in the config file, Mosquitto won't start anymore? Somehow it also seems like no one else has the problem? I reinstalled everything and still nothing works. When I type `sudo systemctl status mosquitto` I get the following:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-08 12:31:46 CET; 1min 50s ago
Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
man:mosquitto(8)
Process: 630 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 631 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 632 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 633 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 634 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 634 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 91ms

Dec 08 12:31:46 MyPI systemd\[1\]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 08 12:31:46 MyPI systemd\[1\]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Dec 08 12:31:46 MyPI systemd\[1\]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 08 12:31:46 MyPI systemd\[1\]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 12:31:46 MyPI systemd\[1\]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
```

Configuration file:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example
pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

EDIT: I now changed the listener to port 1884. And now it worked. Could it be maybe, that the Wi-Fi-Router does have some settings where it blocks every Port on 1883 or something?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the configuration that causes the malfunction?

Comment: Sure! I Hope this what you want: ```# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

Comment: If I remove ```listener 1883``` and ```allow_anonymous true``` everything works fine

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74729986/edit) the question to show the config file (do not post it as a comment) that caused the failure, so we can see it with all the correct line breaks.

Comment: Also include the content of `/var/log/mosquitto/moquitto.log` as this is possible it will have logged the problem with the config file

Comment: The fact is launches before with a different port number then it is most likely that the port 1883 is already in use, which implies that another broker is already running.